# Docker container Restarting (210) means?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, exit-code

I have a passbolt docker container and I have added:

```
restart: always
```

in my docker-compose.yml file.
When I check `docker ps -a` shell shows the status of the container

> Restarting (210)

.
What does 210 it mean? I couldn`t find what does exit code 210 implies.

Answer (score 0):

That means It encountered an *error* when docker tries to *start* container. Because of `restart:always` it restart always when there is an error.

Comment: If i remember correctly, that means it has been restarted 210 times